# I tried to transfer token EOSDAC, but getting below error, can someone help me in this

Tags: tokens, transfer

`cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io transfer ge4dimrzgige ironmanineos " 0.0001 EOSDAC"`

> 157492ms thread-0   main.cpp:2712                 main                 ] Failed with error: unspecified (0)
>   Symbol EOSDAC is not supported by token contract eosio.token

I tried even like this

`nalam@LAPTOP-1K8NT0S9 MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io transfer -c eosdactokens ge4dimrzgige ironmanineos " 0.0001 EOSDAC"`

> 320284ms thread-0   main.cpp:2712                 main                 ] Failed with error: unspecified (0)
>   Symbol EOSDAC is not supported by token contract eosio.token

`cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io transfer ge4dimrzgige ironmanineos " 0.0001 EOSDAC"`

> 435326ms thread-0   main.cpp:2712                 main                 ] Failed with error: unspecified (0)
>   Symbol EOSDAC is not supported by token contract eosio.token

can someone check what is the wrong in above 3 commands

Comment: if I am doing completely wrong please tell me how to do this transaction

Comment: I haven't kept up to date with eosDac, but can you confirm their tokens are actually deployed and exist on the eosio.token contract?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question to something like "How to solve: unspecified (0) Symbol EOSDAC is not supported by token contract eosio.token"

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my question.

cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io push action eosadddddddd transfer '[ "ge4dimrzgige", "ironmanineos", "0.0001 ADD", "m" ]' -p ge4dimrzgige

as of now the eosdac token is frozen for 24 hrs, I checked above command for ADD coin and it worked so it will work for eosdac too.

Comment: yes, use the push action, the transfer in cleos only support eosio.token

Comment: eosDAC was dropped frozen for validation checks - unfrozen on 26th June 2018 15:00 UTC - just use push action eosdactokens transfer